# Y-axis scale with ZedGraph

Tags: zedgraph

I don't understand this axis scaling. I'm able to set the max/min by 
changing `GraphPane.Y2Axis.Scale.Min/Max`.

However, this decouples the bars from the scale. The bars are at the exact same place as before, even though the scale change. So obviously, they are not related anymore.

If I set the max/min, I obviously want the bars to be zoomed in the y direction, but this doesn't happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the property `IsY2Axis` to `True`.